# Zimri real name

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, pinchas

What was Zimri real name?

Comment: The pasuk says his name was Zimri. What evidence do you have otherwise?

Comment: Vote to close, parallel to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2022/759

Answer (score 5):

He had 5:

1. His real name was **Shelumiel ben Tzurishaday** (I wonder if this is where that insult comes from?)
2. **Zimri**- because of all the relations he had with Kozbi his eggs (scrotum) became strange **"She'Na'aseh ke'Beitzah ha'Muzeres"**
3. **Ben Salu**-because he either caused the people to describe his family as a sinful one or he caused Hashem to examine their sins.
4. **Shaul**- because he lent himself out for Aveiros
5. **Ben ha'Cana'anis**- Because he acted like somone from Canan that meaning immorally.

All this is from [Sanhedrin 82b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=82b&format=pdf) (stuff they dont do in Yeshiva or day school)

Comment: The Midrash says that when he brought his korban of the korbanos haNesiim, he tripped on the way. From there was born the Yiddish term "Ah Shlemiel!"

Comment: are you serious?

Comment: Dead serious. The Midrash says he tripped.

Comment: Others say it is from the Hebrew שלא מועיל See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Yiddish_origin

Comment: Sorry. That's Aramaic.

Comment: "HaMuzeres" doesn't mean strange - it means damaged in some way (Artscroll calls it "addled").